# Is $l_2$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ the only norm for which it is equal to its dual norm?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, dual-spaces, matrix-analysis

Given any norm $\|.\|$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, its dual norm $\|.\|^D$ is defined as the following:
$\|v\|^D = \sup_{\|x\|\leq 1} |(v,x)|$, where $(,)$ is the standard Euclidean Inner product. Under that definition, it turns out that the dual norm of the $l_p$ norm is $l_q$, when $1/p+1/q=1$. That implies that for $l_2$, it is equal to the dual norm. Now I wanted to think about the converse: If $\|.\|$ is a norm such that $\|.\| = \|.\|^D$, then is $\|.\|=l_2$? After being unable to find anything online, I wrote the following justification:

Consider any vector in the boundary of the ball of radius $1$ in $\|.\|$ :
\begin{align*}
    1 = \|x\| = \|x\|^D = \sup\left\{\left|\sum^n_i x_iv_i\right|: \|v\| \leq 1\right\}
\end{align*}
Using C-S Inequality (with $(,)$ denoting the usual inner product) we have:
\begin{align*}
    |(x,v)| \leq \|x\|_2 \|v\|_2 
\end{align*}
where equality holds if and only if $x,v$ are linearly dependent. Considering that, let $v = x$. Then $\|v\| = 1$ and we have:
\begin{align*}
     |{(x,v)}| = \|x\|_2^2 \implies \|x\|^D = \|x\| = 1 \geq \|x\|^2_2 \implies 1 \geq \|x\|_2
\end{align*}
Suppose $\exists v_0$ such that $\|v_0\|<1$, and $\|x\|^D \leq |{(x,v_0)}|$ . Then consider $v' = \frac{v}{\|v_0\|}$. We will have $\|{(x,v)}\| \leq \|{x}\|^D \leq |(x,v_0)| \implies \|v_0\|\geq 1$. Hence we have a contradiction.

Consider the functional defined by $f: \overline{B_1}(0)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as $f(v) = |(x,v)|$, where $B$ denotes the ball in $\|.\|$. Then by the compactness of the unit ball in any norm, and continuity of $f$, it attains maxima; let that point be denoted by $v_0$. Then by the earlier paragraph, $\|v_0\|=1$. However, we showed that whenever $\|v_0\| =1$, we should get $\|v_0\|_2 \leq 1$. Hence we get:
\begin{align*}
    \left|{\sum^n_i x_iv_i}\right| \leq |{(x,v_0)}| \leq \|x\|_2\|v_0\|_2 \leq \|x\|_2 \implies 1 = \|x\|^D \leq \|x\|_2
\end{align*}
Hence we get the following for any unit vector:
\begin{align*}
   \|x\| = \|x\|_2
\end{align*}
Now given a general non zero vector, consider:
\begin{align*}
    1 = \|{\frac{x}{\|x\|}}\| =  \|{\frac{x}{\|x\|}}\|_2 \implies \|x\|= \|x\|_2\  \square
\end{align*}

1. Is the proposed solution correct? Is there a better way to see the result?
2. Can this notion be meaniningfully extended in any sense to infinite dimensions?

Comment: Really interesting question (+1)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $V$  denote a subspace of square summable real valued sequences with a norm $\|\cdot \|.$ For example $V= \mathcal{F}$, the subspace of all the sequences with finitely many nonzero terms or $V=\ell^2.$ Assume the norm is self-dual, i.e.
$$\|x\|=\sup\left \{ \left |\sum_{j=1}^\infty x_jy_j\right | \,:\, \|y\|\le 1\right \}\quad (*)$$
In particular $(*)$ means that the RHS is finite.
Let $\|x\|=1.$ Then
$$1=\sup\left \{ \left |\sum_{j=1}^\infty x_jy_j\right | \,:\, \|y\|\le 1\right \}$$
Hence plugging in $y=x$ gives
$$1\ge \sum_{j=1}^\infty x_j^2=\|x\|_2^2$$
Thus $\|x\|_2\le 1=\|x\|.$ By homogeneity this implies
$$\|x\|_2\le \|x\|$$
Fix $x\neq 0.$  There exists $y^{(n)}$ such that $\|y^{(n)}\|\le 1$ and
$$ \left |\sum_{j=1}^\infty x_jy^{(n)}_j \right | \ge \|x\|-{1\over n} $$
By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we get
$$\|x\|-{1\over n} \le \|x\|_2\|y^{(n)}\|_2\le \|x\|_2\,\|y^{(n)}\|\le \|x\|$$
Hence $$\|x\|_2\ge \lim_n\|x\|_2\|y^{(n)}\|=\|x\|$$
Thus we have obtained $\|x\|=\|x\|_2.$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I just wish to clarify that why is the supremum of $|\sum^{\infty}_{i=1} x_iy_i|$ guaranteed to exist when $y$ can vary over the unit ball in an $\|.\|$?

Comment: It exists by the assumption of the self-duality.  I have added a sentence after  formula $(*).$

Comment: Hi @RyszardSzwarc. There is a [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4553558/121671) that you may enjoy and which may require some clever constriction or result from analysis (case $2<p<\infty$).

Comment: Hi @OliverDíaz Nice to hear from you. How come I overlooked that problem ? If it does not require going deep into measure theoretic considerations, I will make a try. Thanks.